# windows cmd.exe intereaction with other apps with the pipe

Tags: pipe, console-application

I have read about windows console applications recently and the pipes. I know that cmd.exe is just another console application. I have been reading this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164014.aspx#S1. What I am questioning myself and maybe is a question not to simple to answer is that when I execute a program from the cmd.exe and redirect the stdout of that first application to a second application's stdin, from what I read cmd.exe do all he needs to do to redirect the standard stdin and stdout to point to the right places. My question is how cmd.exe do this. I mean application 1 and application 2 are already compiled and cmd.exe is another application. What I thought is that cmd.exe have some kind of funcions to interact with the kernel and tells the kernel how to manipulate the process start of the two applications(for example telling where the stdout and stdin of both applications should point)So from this point of view it is the kernel that is told by cmd to start the applications with another stdin and stdout. Probably I'm wrong but I just wanted to have a litte more of the insight of the process in a pipe.

Comment: Consider taking all of this and condensing it into a one sentence question. You don't even really need to delete what you have. Just add the bottom, you could add something like "Basically, my question is this: ________." You definitely don't need stuff like "probably I'm wrong but..." and "I mean..." It only makes it harder for the reader to figure out what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) allows starting another process with redirected standard streams by setting the `hStd*` handles in the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. These handles are then accessed by the target process, either directly (not often) or through a standard library such as msvcrt (most common). The handle can be obtained in the target process through [`GetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When redirecting from one process to another, a pipe is usually used. This can be created with [`CreatePipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which returns two `HANDLE`s, one for reading and one for writing. The write handle is used as the `hStdOutput` of the first process and the read handle is used as the `hStdInput` of the second process.

Comment: And where should I implement the CreatePipe. For example I am creating the first process or program and I have a second one. Where is implemented the CreatePipe, when I'm programming the first process or in the second process?

Comment: `cmd.exe` creates the pipe. If you want to communicate with a child process yourself, you create a pipe and use it when calling `CreateProcess`